# Transfer data by ultrasound in android java

Tags: java, android, implementation, transfer

I want to implement an app that looks like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPntMT_8UuQ

Basically - Two mobiles that my app open and one mobile sends bits like 01010101
and in the second mobile I received this sequence...

I read about sinus function to send sound but unsuccessful.

I want to implement in java lang the app,
the cover of the app is ready, but I don't know how to continue that I
click "Transfer".

Is there an idea where to start?

Comment: Have a look at Bluetooth. Make an app that runs on both the mobiles. One acts as client, other as server.

Comment: how did it help me ? i asked guidance to implement the app in java...

Comment: *Is there an idea where to start?* I gave you just that.

Comment: thank you but its not helped me,
basiclly i want to implements this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPntMT_8UuQ where to start?

Comment: http://rnd.azoft.com/mobile-app-transering-data-using-ultrasound/

Comment: http://nearbytes.com/en/

Comment: The first link has been seen and there's no practical code
The second link is sdk that costs money...
i want to implements this app alone in java i needs guides,codes,practical helps.